# Как получить ключ первого записанного элемента в LocalStorage?

Tags: javascript, html5, localstorage

Если при попытке записи хранилище окажется переполненным, хочу удалить наиболее старую запить, чтобы появилось место для новой. 
Я понимаю что критерием заполненности является не количество записей, а объем памяти, но у меня примерно одинаковые по объему записи. В крайнем случае можно удалить десяток наиболее старых записей. Вопрос в том, как объяснить какие записи являются старыми. Все записи пронумерованы по порядку, и удалить записи с номерами с 0 по 10 не сложно, но это частный случай. При повторном переполнении этих записей уже не будет.

Comment: localStorage.removeItem(localStorage.key(0));  При удалении номера сдвинутся. Это в вырожденном случае, когда нам все равно на изменение записей в сторадже, они только добавлются. Если не все равно, надо хранить в сторадже дату изменения и поверх нее написать обертку

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Недавно писал учебный пример по localStorage, возможно, вам пригодятся некоторые принципы работы скрипта http://romanzhivo.com/localstorage-methods-properties-example/#user-visit-notification

Как вариант - ввести условный разделитель и записывать в хранилище вместе с ключом через разделитель время и дату сделанной записи, а при необходимости удаления сверять время и дату. Грубый пример для сравнения двух записей может быть таким:

```
        function getTimeFunc() {
            var actualTime = new Date();

            if(actualTime.getSeconds() < 10) {
                var seconds = '0' + actualTime.getSeconds();
            } else {
                var seconds = actualTime.getSeconds();
            }

            if(actualTime.getMinutes() < 10) {
                var minutes = '0' + actualTime.getMinutes();
            } else {
                var minutes = actualTime.getMinutes();
            }

            if(actualTime.getHours() >= 10 && actualTime.getHours() <= 23) {
                var hours = actualTime.getHours();
            } else {
                var hours = '0' + actualTime.getHours();
            }

            if(actualTime.getDate() < 10) {
                var currentDate = '0' + actualTime.getDate();
            } else {
                var currentDate = actualTime.getDate();
            }
            if(actualTime.getMonth() + 1 < 10) {
                var currenMonth = '0' + (actualTime.getMonth() + 1);
            } else {
                var currenMonth = actualTime.getMonth() + 1;
            }

            var currentYear = actualTime.getFullYear();
            var currentTime = hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds;

            return {
                time: currentTime+', '+ currentDate + '.' + currenMonth + '.' + currentYear
            }
        }

        function writeLS1() {
            var time = getTimeFunc().time;

            localStorage.someData1 = 123 + '; time ' + time;
        }

        function writeLS2() {
            var time = getTimeFunc().time;

            localStorage.someData2 = 123 + '; time ' + time;
        }
        writeLS2();

        function getLSdata() {
            var data1 = localStorage.someData1;
            var data2 = localStorage.someData2;
            var position1 = data1.indexOf('time');
            var position2 = data2.indexOf('time');
            var time1 = data1.substring(position1+5, 30);
            var time2 = data2.substring(position2+5, 30);

            var hours1 = parseInt(time1.substring(0,2));
            var minutes1 = parseInt(time1.substring(3,5));
            var seconds1 = parseInt(time1.substring(6,8));
            var date1 = parseInt(time1.substring(10,12));
            var month1 = parseInt(time1.substring(13,15));
            var year1 = parseInt(time1.substring(16,20));

            var hours2 = parseInt(time2.substring(0,2));
            var minutes2 = parseInt(time2.substring(3,5));
            var seconds2 = parseInt(time2.substring(6,8));
            var date2 = parseInt(time2.substring(10,12));
            var month2 = parseInt(time2.substring(13,15));
            var year2 = parseInt(time2.substring(16,20));

            if(
                hours1 <= hours2
                && minutes1 <= minutes2
                && seconds1 <= seconds2
                && date1 <= date2
                && month1 <= month2
                && year1 <= year2
            ) {
                alert('Удалить data1');
            } else {
                alert('Удалить data2');
            }   
        }
        setTimeout(function() {
            writeLS1();
            getLSdata();
        }, 2000);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Romanzhivo/mpwxLswe